# Can you use two sets of brackets side-by-side within a quote?

Tags: quotations, square-brackets

Specifically, I want to use brackets to indicate a break in the quote (with an ellipse in the brackets) as well as brackets to format the quote to fit my sentence.

For example, if I were to quote from Rousseau's *Second Discourse*, could I write:

Rousseau's conception of the state of nature is one before the introduction of private property, in which each individual "undertook only what a single person could accomplish [...] [and where] they lived free, healthy, honest and happy lives"

I'm aware that I could rewrite the sentence to make the double brackets unnecessary, but I'd like to know if they are generally acceptable for future reference.

Comment: It's a bit precious, in that it calls attention to the editor's process. You can't go with "accomplish [... and where] they"?

Comment: I had considered "[... and where]" as it seems the least obtrusive, but I wasn't sure if the ellipse needed to be bracketed by itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would not bracket the ellipsis, since you are already in a quotation. The brackets are needed for the words that *you add* to make the quotation understandable. Thus, in your example:

> each individual “undertook only what a single person could accomplish ... [and where] they lived free, healthy, honest and happy lives”